# Insert Event to Calendar With Async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-calendar-api

I have below code which is working fine to insert event in calendar. It is class extended to activity so when this is called , a blank activity is opened. I want to perform this through Async Task.

Activity Class:

```
  private static final Level LOGGING_LEVEL = Level.OFF;

    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";

    static final String TAG = "CalendarAuth";



    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 0;

    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1;

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 2;

    private final static int ADD_OR_EDIT_CALENDAR_REQUEST = 3;
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service;
    final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

    final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleAccountCredential credential;
    Event event;
    CalendarModel model = new CalendarModel();

    String title, description;
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;

    int numAsyncTasks;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smspayremin);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rest);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
        final SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client").setLevel(LOGGING_LEVEL);
        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

        // Calendar client
        client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Google-CalendarAndroidSample/1.0")
                .build();

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.smartrem), true).apply();
            }
        });




        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("remtitle")) {
                title = bundle.getString("remtitle");
                description = bundle.getString("remdesc");
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }




    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    haveGooglePlayServices();
                } else {
                    checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // AsyncLoadCalendars.run(this);
                } else {
                    chooseAccount();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.commit();
                        //   AsyncLoadCalendars.run(this);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }


    public void createEvent(GoogleAccountCredential mCredential) {

        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                .setApplicationName("Created By Mini4Me")
                .build();


        event = new Event()
                .setSummary(title)
                /*.setLocation("Dhaka")*/
                .setDescription(description);

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(new Date());
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                .setTimeZone(timeZone.getID());
        event.setStart(start);

        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(addDays(new Date(), 10));
        Log.e("start D ", startDateTime + "End Date " + endDateTime + timeZone.getID());
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(endDateTime).setTimeZone(timeZone.getID());
        event.setEnd(end);

        String[] recurrence = new String[]{"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
        event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

       /* EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[]{
                new EventAttendee().setEmail("abir@aksdj.com"),
                new EventAttendee().setEmail("asdasd@andlk.com"),
        };
        event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));*/

        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[]{
                //new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };
        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);

        final String calendarId = "primary";

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
                    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
                    if (title != null) {
                        title = null;
                        finish();
                        finish();
                        //System.exit(0);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();


    }


    public static Date addDays(Date date, int days) {
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, days);

        return cal.getTime();
    }

    public boolean checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(final int connectionStatusCode) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                        connectionStatusCode, SMSDataFetch.this, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void haveGooglePlayServices() {
        // check if there is already an account selected

        if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            // ask user to choose account
            chooseAccount();
        } else {

            if (title != null && description != null) {
                createEvent(credential);
            }

        }
    }

    private void chooseAccount() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.smartrem), true).apply();
        button.setText("Disable Smart Reminder");
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

       if (checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            haveGooglePlayServices();
        }
    }
}
```

TO insert event I made below AsyncTask class but it is not working and giving me NPE at various points like credential, event.

```
public class BGTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private static final String TAG = "BGTask";
    Event event;
    final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

    final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
    private String title, message;
    private Context context;
    GoogleAccountCredential credential;
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;
    public BGTask(Context context, String title, String message) {
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString("accountName", null));

        credential.setSelectedAccountName("ankurjain30@gmail.com");
        // Calendar client
        client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Google-CalendarAndroidSample/1.0")
                .build();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            haveGooglePlayServices();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void haveGooglePlayServices() {
        // check if there is already an account selected
        if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            // ask user to choose account

        } else {

            cre();

        }
    }


    public void cre() {
        event = new Event()
                .setSummary(title)
                /*.setLocation("Dhaka")*/
                .setDescription(message);

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(new Date());
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                .setTimeZone(timeZone.getID());
        event.setStart(start);

        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(new Date());
        Log.e("start D ", startDateTime + "End Date " + endDateTime + timeZone.getID());
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(endDateTime).setTimeZone(timeZone.getID());
        event.setEnd(end);

        String[] recurrence = new String[]{"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
        event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

       /* EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[]{
                new EventAttendee().setEmail("abir@aksdj.com"),
                new EventAttendee().setEmail("asdasd@andlk.com"),
        };
        event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));*/

        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[]{
                //new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };
        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);

        final String calendarId = "primary";
        try {
            event = mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one help me in fixing it.

Comment: Where are you calling the Asynctask in your activity? I dont see it.

Comment: Asynct is not called here, it is called from mainactivitiy as with below line  new BGTask(getApplicationContext(), "Hi", "Async Teset").execute();

Comment: Check if you're getting all values in your constructor method. I guess the values coming in could be null, which could be causing NPE.